# $P(A|B)$ in terms of $P(A|B,C)$ and $P(A|B,C^c)$

Tags: conditional-probability

Consider three events $A,B,C$ not independent

I have the impression using Venn diagrams that the following relation holds

$P(A|B)=P(A|B,C)+P(A|B,C^c)$ but I want to prove it

This is what I have done

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A,B,C)+P(A,B,C^c)}{P(B)}$
so,

$\frac{P(A,B,C)P(C|B)}{P(B) P(C|B)}+\frac{P(A,B,C^c)P(C^c|B)}{P(B) P(C^c|B)}=$
$P(C|B) P(A|B,C)+P(C^c|B) P(A|B,C^c)$ which is not exactly what I want.

Am I doing something wrong with the math? Or is just that $P(A|B)\neq P(A|B,C)+P(A|B,C^c)$

Thank you

Comment: This is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

Answer (score 1):

This relation does not hold true.

Let $X$ be the result of a 6-sided dice throwing. Let $A = \{X=6\}$, $B = \{X \text{ is even}\}$ and $C = \{X=2\}$.

Then $P(A \mid B) = 1/3$ while $P(A \mid B,C) = P(A \mid C) = 0$ and $P(A \mid B, C^c) = P(X=6 \mid X =4 \text{ or } X=6)=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}\\
P(A)&=&P(A,C) +P(A,C^c)\\
&=&P(A|C)P(C)+P(A|C^c)P(C^c) \\
&\neq& P(A|C)+P(A|C^c)\\
\end{array}$$

or derived from this (with the additional condition B)

$$\begin{array}\\
P(A|B)&=&P(A,C|B) +P(A,C^c|B)\\
&=&P(A|B,C)P(C|B)+P(A|B,C^c)P(C^c|B) \\
&\neq& P(A|B,C)+P(A|B,C^c)\\
\end{array}$$

Probably the first line is what gave your intuition from the Venn diagram (the area of $P(A)$, in the diagram, is the sum of the areas for $P(A,C)$ and $P(A,C^c)$).

$P(A|C)$, which you use would be the *relative* area of $P(A,C)/P(C)$.

Using a table would give a better intuition than a Venn diagram.